# Are props passed from parent to child by default with `this`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning through an open source project [here](https://github.com/ilhammeidi/boss-lite). I have deployed it and it works. So the below pasted code is valid for sure.

I was looking at a `Header` component in `Header.js`:

```
class Header extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
  };

  render() {
    const {
      classes,
      toggleDrawerOpen,
      margin,
      turnDarker,
    } = this.props;

    return (

      .... some code ....

    )
```

I see that `classes` is passed as a prop from the parent. So I looked into the parent component, `Dashboard`. Here is the code:

```
import { Header, Sidebar, BreadCrumb } from './../../components';
import { toggleAction, openAction, playTransitionAction } from './../../actions/UiActions';
import styles from './appStyles-jss';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  state = {
    transform: 0,
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    // Scroll content to top
    const mainContent = document.getElementById('mainContent');
    mainContent.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);

    // Set expanded sidebar menu
    const currentPath = this.props.history.location.pathname;
    this.props.initialOpen(currentPath);

    // Play page transition
    this.props.loadTransition(true);

    // Execute all arguments when page changes
    this.unlisten = this.props.history.listen(() => {
      mainContent.scrollTo(0, 0);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.props.loadTransition(true);
      }, 500);
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    const mainContent = document.getElementById('mainContent');
    mainContent.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll = (event) => {
    const scoll = event.target.scrollTop;
    this.setState({
      transform: scoll
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      classes,  // classes is here 
      route,
      toggleDrawer,
      sidebarOpen,
      loadTransition,
      pageLoaded
    } = this.props;
    const darker = true;
    return (
      <div className={classes.appFrameInner}>


         // NOTE: Header component is here but I don't see how classes is passed to it. 
        <Header toggleDrawerOpen={toggleDrawer} turnDarker={this.state.transform > 30 && darker} margin={sidebarOpen} />


        <Sidebar
          open={sidebarOpen}
          toggleDrawerOpen={toggleDrawer}
          loadTransition={loadTransition}
          turnDarker={this.state.transform > 30 && darker}
        />
        <main className={classNames(classes.content, !sidebarOpen && classes.contentPadding)} id="mainContent">
          <div className={classes.bgbar} />
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can see that the `classes` prop is passed from `Dashboard`'s parent. However, I was expecting some syntax that shows it is passed into the child  `Header` component.
See the "NOTE" line in the code, nothing was said about passing the entire props to `Header` component or passing the const `classes` specifically to `Header`.

How is `classes` passed from parent (Dashbaord) to child (Header)?

Comment: The classes prop _isn't_ passed from Dashboard to Header, as you can see in the render method. I'd guess there's some higher-order component involved like [`withStyles(Header)`](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component) but without a [mre] it's hard to say. The short answer is no: not all props are passed automatically from parent to child.

Comment: What are the values of both `classes` props? Why are you assuming they are passed down till the `Header` child?

Comment: Yep, it's a HOC (and I guessed exactly the right one!): https://github.com/ilhammeidi/boss-lite/blob/5257a927025607a23364a76e0adc3155d24e00d9/src/app/components/Header/Header.js#L72

Comment: @jonrsharpe  Thank you. I'll learn about Higher-order component now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `classes` prop is not passed from parent `Dashboard` to child `Header`.

The `classes` prop is made available **directly to your `Header` component** using [the wrapping `withStyles` HOC when exporting your component](https://github.com/ilhammeidi/boss-lite/blob/master/src/app/components/Header/Header.js#L72):

```
export default withStyles(styles)(Header);
```

This approach is commonly known as *CSS-in-JS* and you can read more details [in the *material-ui* styles](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/) documentation.